# Image not copied across to new html page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

I have a button that copies the content of a html page into a new page and then calls the browsers print function.

The only problem is that it is not copying across a < img>

JS:

```
function PrintElem(elem)
{
    Popup($(elem).html());
}
function Popup(data) 
{
var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=600,width=800');
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Hire Form</title>');

mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
mywindow.document.write(data);
mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

mywindow.print();
mywindow.close();

return true; 
}
```

html Img:

```
<img src="../../../Corp/SiteAssets/Intranet%20Branding/Logo.png" alt="Test"></img>
```

**EDIT**
When I change the img url to its full url it works in IE and Firefox but not chrome.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8kgmzcf8/1/ ?

Comment: Maybe the image is not loaded yet, you need to call `mywindow.print();` after the image have fully loaded.

Comment: @AdrianDelaPiedra How do you tell when the image is loaded?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Your fiddle works fine, which is how i expected my code to work. If it makes a difference (it shouldn't..) the environment is Sharepoint 2013

Comment: A couple of things. What are you putting into PrintElem() as input? A potential problem is that you are immediately closing the popup with window.close(); and if you are using a local file:// for the image that could be causing errors.

Comment: @Roland you can add onload in your img element, like '<img onload="window.print()" src="path here" alt="Test"></img>'

Comment: @AdrianDelaPiedra the normal print() works fine its when i try and copy the image to a new page to print from that it doesn't come up in chrome (see edit).

Comment: @wrleskovec See Edit. Using the full url works except for in chrome from some reason. Implement Jelly's answer below and the print window never comes up. I am passing in a div with most just text contained in it which comes up fine.

Comment: Adrian's method works on chrome. You can just manipulate the element before you write it to include onload attribute. You need to make sure the window.close() happens after you call window.print() thought or just not call it at all.

Comment: @wrleskovec how do i add the onload element as I write it in? Also the image is at the top of page so it's one of the first items to be written across

Comment: just use $(elem).attr('onload', 'window.print()').html();

Comment: @Roland sorry for the late response, i took my lunch. Please see my answer below if it answers your query, i cant post it here for it has an example.

Answer (score 0):

I can get your point.

please see https://jsfiddle.net/j34aeafp/.

```
function PrintElem(elem) {
  Popup('asdfsdf <img id="needImage" src="//placehold.it/64/fff000" alt="Test"></img>');
}

function Popup(data) {
  var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=600,width=800');
  mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Hire Form</title>');

  mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
  mywindow.document.write(data);
  mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

  mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
  mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

  // listen img onload then call print
  mywindow.document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].onload = function(){
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
  };

  return true;
}

PrintElem();
```

Comment: Or you can just use what @Adrian Dela Piedra say,it did same

Comment: See OP edit. Doesn't work in chrome and with this  check the print window never comes up in chrome (on load or by button press).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the onload event to the body so that you don't need to modify or add attributes for each of the image element like below.

```
function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=600,width=800');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Hire Form</title>');

    mywindow.document.write('</head><body onload="window.print(); window.close();">');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

    return true; 
}
```